# Base R ifelse test for a span of temperature values

Tags: r, if-statement, time-series

I am aware that this question has been asked for other cases before, but none of the answers matched my case well. I have been trying hard but didn´t get it working for my code. I believe that there is a simple solution and appreciate your help.

My Data looks like that:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2018-05-18 00:00")
tseq <- seq(from = start, length.out = 1440, by = "10 mins")
Measurings <- data.frame(
  Time = tseq,
  Temp = sample(10:37,1440, replace = TRUE, set.seed(seed = 10)),
  Variable1 = sample(1:200,1440, replace = TRUE, set.seed(seed = 187)),
  Variable2 = sample(300:800,1440, replace = TRUE, set.seed(seed = 333))
)

Measurings$heat25 <- ifelse(Measurings$Temp >= 25 ,"summer", "normal")
Measurings$heat30 <- ifelse(Measurings$Temp > 30 ,"heat", "normal")
```

This works, and I need the Columns for choosing my data based on temperature values.
Now I need a new column indicating wether the temperature is between 25 °C and 30° C. I expected to be able to combine test arguments like that:

```
Measurings$summer <- ifelse(Measurings$Temp >= 25 && < 30, "summer", "rest"))
```

But I get an error.

How can I simply add a new column indicating if `Temp` is between 25°C and 30°C?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: See `help('&&')` for an explanation of how logical functions work in R. From `help('&&')`: "& and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly modify your code

```
Measurings$summer <- ifelse(Measurings$Temp >= 25 & Measurings$Temp < 30, "summer", "rest"))
```

You only have to use a single `&` operator for vectorized operations